# How would you test a button using useNavigate() with Jest in React?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am having a bit of trouble with this - here is a snippet of my code:

```
    function addProduct() {
            navigate('/adding')
     }
.
.
.
return(
        <React.Fragment>
                <button className = "button" data-testid="addnewpage" onClick={addProduct}>Add New Product</button>
                    <br></br>
                {useProducts}
        </React.Fragment>
        )
```

I want to test `<button className = "button" data-testid="addnewpage" onClick={addProduct}>Add New Product</button>` using Jest, and see if it navigates to the right page. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to mock useNavigate check code below

```
const mockedUsedNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
   ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useNavigate: () => mockedUsedNavigate,
}));
```

Comment: Thanks! I am a bit confused as to why this piece of code tests useNavigate()?